# Gathering performance metrics of a cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to gather some performance metrics like:

1. Time taken for DB to reach a consistent state across multiple DCs for a given key/row.
2. Data load on each node (including the memtable that is available from cfstats). Currently I am thinking of parsing results from cfstats and getting the info I need for a particular column family.
3. When I add or remove a node from the cluster, how long it would take to automatically distribute the load among itself?
4. Distribution of keys among the nodes. How many keys each node contain given a CF?

How can I accurately gather these statistics? Are there any tools that I can use?

Thanks,

Chethan

Answer (score 0):

Why not start with Cassandras Nodetool?